# learning to use loops by calculating cumulative probability from probability of each trial in R

Tags: r, loops, probability

I've struggled long enough on my own to find an answer. I promise I'll try to learn from the solutions.  For the sake of learning, I would like to understand *how to do it with explicit loops*, but if you want to share a vectorized approach as a bonus that is also greatly appreciated.

Say I'm going to play a game once each day and I know the probability of victory each day.  I want a function which takes that vector of probabilities and returns the cumulative probability of success on at least one day.  So if I play for 3 days in a row and the probability of victory was 0.5 each day then my function should return "0.875, 0.75, 0.5"

Here is my most recent failed attempt at writing this function:

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
  for (i in 1:length(prob_today)) {
    for (j in i:length(prob_today)) {
      p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] - ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
    }
  }
  p_cum
}

prob_daily <- c(.5,.5,.5)
prob_cum(prob_daily)
```

Comment: Standard-Statistical-Trick:: If the task is for probability on any day prior to day X then you can subtract the probability of non-success to day X from 1. (I also do not understand why the order should not be: .5, .75, .875?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working though each problem at a time:

You have a loop over `i` which doesn't do anything; it just performs the same calculations multiple times and each time overwrites the results (with the same results). Drop that.

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
  for (j in i:length(prob_today)) {
    p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] - ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
  }
  p_cum
}
```

This still has problems. For `j=1`, you try to access `p_cum[0]` which is a zero-length vector and your calculation assumes a one-length vector. That is why you get the error message

```
Error in p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j - 1] - ((1 - p_cum[j - 1]) * prob_today[j]) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Initialize `p_cum[1]` and then loop over the rest.

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
  p_cum[1] <- prob_today[1]
  for (j in 2:length(prob_today)) {
    p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] - ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
  }
  p_cum
}
```

This looping construct is potentially dangerous. It works so long as `prob_today` is at least length 2 but will behave unexpectedly if the length is 1. Better is

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
  p_cum[1] <- prob_today[1]
  for (j in seq_along(prob_today)[-1]) {
    p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] - ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
  }
  p_cum
}
```

Now we get to a real problem: your algorithm is wrong. The probability of getting at least one win by day `j` is the probability of getting at least one by day `j-1` PLUS the probability of getting a win on day `j` given that there hasn't been a win to that point. You have a minus.

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
  p_cum[1] <- prob_today[1]
  for (j in seq_along(prob_today)[-1]) {
    p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] + ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
  }
  p_cum
}
```

Now you have a function that works:

```
> prob_cum(prob_daily)
[1] 0.500 0.750 0.875
> prob_cum(c(0.5, 0.01, 0.99))
[1] 0.50000 0.50500 0.99505
```

The fully vectorized solution follows from expressing the probability differently. The probability of getting at least one win is 1 minus the probability of getting all losses up to that day. Those are independent probabilities, so are just a product of getting a loss each day.

```
prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
  1 - cumprod(1-prob_today)
}
```

which gives the same results

```
> prob_cum(prob_daily)
[1] 0.500 0.750 0.875
> prob_cum(c(0.5, 0.01, 0.99))
[1] 0.50000 0.50500 0.99505
```

and works for single values and empty vectors without any additional adjustments needed

```
> prob_cum(c(0.75))
[1] 0.75
> prob_cum(c())
numeric(0)
```

Comment: ~60 times slower than the vectorized approach.

Comment: @DWin I'm somewhat surprised it is even that fast. Although it does use pre-allocation rather than extending vectors which is where many loop-based solutions really slow down. But given that the question asked for a loop based solution, acknowledging that vectorization would be good to know too, I gave a loop based solution.

Comment: I actually read it incorrectly. I thought it said 'without loops' but that was perhaps just my brain stuck in the "forward"-mode.

Answer (score 5):

```
>  1 - cumprod( 1- c(0.5,0.5,0.5) )
[1] 0.500 0.750 0.875
 # (1- prob_success) is the prob_non_success vector
```

Easily wrapped into a function if needed. Your intial test was not a good one because it did not disclose my original error in not subtracting the success vector from 1 within the cumprod argument.

```
 vec<-runif(100)
 prob_cum <- function(prob_today) {
   p_cum <- rep(0, length(prob_today))
   p_cum[1] <- prob_today[1]
   for (j in seq_along(prob_today)[-1]) {
     p_cum[j] <- p_cum[j-1] + ((1 - p_cum[j-1]) * prob_today[j])
   }
   p_cum
 }
 Prob_vec <- function(vec) 1 - cumprod( 1- vec) 
 require(rbenchmark)
 benchmark( prob_cum(vec) , Prob_vec(vec) ,replications=1000)
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1 prob_cum(vec)         1000   0.538   59.778     0.532    0.008          0         0
#2 Prob_vec(vec)         1000   0.009    1.000     0.008    0.002          0         0
```